# How to load other beans in spring test file when that test file has @DataJpaTest

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

```
@DataJpaTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SqlGroup({
        @Sql(executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD, scripts = "classpath:database/insert.sql"),
})
class DataBaseTest{}
```

I tried removing `@DataJpaTest` and added `@SpringBootTest` and `@Transactional` and i see that test file succesfully passed. But i have lot of files like this. By adding `@Transactional` in all files it is causing out of memory error. so i don't want to go with  `@Transactional`.

Only with `@DataJpaTest` and `@SpringBootTest` i'm seeing initialization Error. So i read in the documentation if i added both `@SpringBootTest` and `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase` i'm seeing few issue with insert sql file error

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Unique index
> or primary key violation:

So overall i want to add other beans but this is stopping `@DataJpaTest`. Is there any other way to get that beans without having above issues.